# Best practices for singers to recover from losing one's voice

Tags: voice, health, voice-training

I am the lead vocalist in a rock band, and I recently nearly had to cancel a performance because I'd been sick and had almost completely lost my voice a few days before the show. Thankfully I was able to recover in time, but I'd like to learn some best practices for getting one's voice back after losing it on account of being sick.